# What is java-rmi.exe?

Tags: java, cgi, rmi

In the JDK's bin directory (at least up to Java 8) on MS-Windows, there is the file `java-rmi.exe`:

```
30.01.2014  15:28            15.752 java-rmi.exe
```

On Unix, there is a similar file called `java-rmi.cgi`, so I suppose these executables have been used to support some (legacy, ancient) CGI interface to RMI (actually, `java-rmi.cgi` is a simple shell script which launches `java`).

I found this site where they explain the usage of `java-rmi.cgi` on Unix, but there is no reference to `java-rmi.exe`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch6.html

So, is `java-rmi.exe` simply the MS-Windows counterpart of `java-rmi.cgi` on Unix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `java-rmi.exe` is a useless file which should never have shown up in the JDK in the first place: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6512052

There is a discussion on removing it again. Best to do: Ignore its existence.

Comment: I accepted this answer, since (If I remember right) its been here slightly before the other one from @Sanjeev :)

Answer (score 2):

yes, I believe you are right in stating that java-rmi.exe is windows counter part of Unix java-rmi.cgi, you should [Check this bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6512052).

Answer (score -2):

java-rmi.exe is known as Java Platform and it is developed by Sun Microsystems . We have seen about 1 different instances of java-rmi.exe in different location.

Is java-rmi.exe using too much CPU or memory ? It's probably your file has been infected with a virus

If you encounter difficulties with java-rmi.exe , you can uninstall the associated program (Start > Control Panel > Add/Remove programs

Java-rmi.exe is usually located in the c:\ProgramData\Adobe\CS5\jre\bin folder

Comment: `java-rmi.exe is known as Java Platform  ...`. Ehm, no - `java-rmi.exe` is NOT the Java Platform.